# Ubuntu on dual boot not properly working because of GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I am carrying the following error some time ago, and I am still not find a solution.

I have a XPS 15 and I did a dual boot (everything went fine). Some time after I had to reinstall Windows 10 and also set up Ubuntu once more, but it is not working well since then. Something on the GRUB remains not correcly configured and I do not know what.

When I run GRUB Customizer, it gets frozen in "loading script (OS Prover)". Also, if I restart from Ubuntu, it gets frozen as well and I need to reset the laptop with the power button.

I noticed something before installing Ubuntu the second time: The boot order still showed "ubuntu". Strange, if I did not have it!

I tried to use some GRUB repair tools. I did it in Ubuntu, but stills I got an error. I paste the report at the end of the message.

Thank you very much for your precious help,

```
Boot Info Script 8f991e4 + Boot-Repair extra info      [Boot-Info 25oct2017]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================


============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

no valid partition table found
"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/nvme0n1                                                       
/dev/nvme0n1p1   BCEF-F16E                              vfat       SYSTEM
/dev/nvme0n1p2                                                     
/dev/nvme0n1p3   AC6E0D026E0CC6D4                       ntfs       
/dev/nvme0n1p4   CA1EF5611EF546CB                       ntfs       Windows RE tools
/dev/nvme0n1p5   76bb7602-518d-4b89-a29e-7096fea18e53   swap       
/dev/nvme0n1p6   ef97b2fc-fe05-4743-a7a3-2e82d9610933   ext4       

========================= "ls -l /dev/disk/by-id" output: ======================

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jan 25 19:52 nvme-PC300_NVMe_SK_hynix_512GB_EJ79N7398105AA14R -> ../../nvme0n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jan 25 19:52 nvme-PC300_NVMe_SK_hynix_512GB_EJ79N7398105AA14R-part1 -> ../../nvme0n1p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jan 25 19:52 nvme-PC300_NVMe_SK_hynix_512GB_EJ79N7398105AA14R-part2 -> ../../nvme0n1p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jan 25 19:52 nvme-PC300_NVMe_SK_hynix_512GB_EJ79N7398105AA14R-part3 -> ../../nvme0n1p3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jan 25 19:52 nvme-PC300_NVMe_SK_hynix_512GB_EJ79N7398105AA14R-part4 -> ../../nvme0n1p4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jan 25 19:52 nvme-PC300_NVMe_SK_hynix_512GB_EJ79N7398105AA14R-part5 -> ../../nvme0n1p5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jan 25 19:52 nvme-PC300_NVMe_SK_hynix_512GB_EJ79N7398105AA14R-part6 -> ../../nvme0n1p6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jan 25 19:52 nvme-eui.ace42e71900a8477 -> ../../nvme0n1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jan 25 19:52 nvme-eui.ace42e71900a8477-part1 -> ../../nvme0n1p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jan 25 19:52 nvme-eui.ace42e71900a8477-part2 -> ../../nvme0n1p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jan 25 19:52 nvme-eui.ace42e71900a8477-part3 -> ../../nvme0n1p3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jan 25 19:52 nvme-eui.ace42e71900a8477-part4 -> ../../nvme0n1p4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jan 25 19:52 nvme-eui.ace42e71900a8477-part5 -> ../../nvme0n1p5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Jan 25 19:52 nvme-eui.ace42e71900a8477-part6 -> ../../nvme0n1p6

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/nvme0n1p1   /boot/efi                vfat       (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/nvme0n1p6   /                        ext4       (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)



ADDITIONAL INFORMATION :
=================== log of boot-repair 20180125_1952 ===================
boot-repair version : 4ppa65
boot-sav version : 4ppa65
boot-sav-extra version : 4ppa65
glade2script version : 3.2.3~ppa4
Warning: failed to translate partition name
boot-repair is executed in installed-session (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, xenial, Ubuntu, x86_64)
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-28-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=ef97b2fc-fe05-4743-a7a3-2e82d9610933 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7

=================== os-prober:
/dev/nvme0n1p6:The OS now in use - Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS CurrentSession:linux
/dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi

=================== blkid:
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="BCEF-F16E" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="a23a62ee-e83a-48df-8e1f-b836ac28b784"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="AC6E0D026E0CC6D4" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="61d26bec-cfa8-42e1-87b3-3388d1ad1f27"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: LABEL="Windows RE tools" UUID="CA1EF5611EF546CB" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="8ef2e10b-1543-403d-863d-cabaf373e330"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: UUID="76bb7602-518d-4b89-a29e-7096fea18e53" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="34d4d75b-c85f-4145-96a0-ca268c1fbf88"
/dev/nvme0n1p6: UUID="ef97b2fc-fe05-4743-a7a3-2e82d9610933" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="1a06129b-f0b4-4fed-8535-94c0bca3d31e"
/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="a5a609e3-db31-4b1a-ba2f-4788781ba932" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="049eda6f-c34f-448f-a4ff-4c96e4a00fd9"


1 disks with OS, 2 OS : 1 Linux, 0 MacOS, 1 Windows, 0 unknown type OS.

Windows not detected by os-prober on nvme0n1p3.

=================== /etc/grub.d/ :
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Jan 25 19:40 grub.d
total 84
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  9791 Jun 21  2017 00_header
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  6258 Mär 15  2016 05_debian_theme
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12512 Jun 21  2017 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11082 Jun 21  2017 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1992 Jan 28  2016 20_memtest86+
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   580 Jan 25 19:40 25_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11692 Jun 21  2017 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1418 Jun 21  2017 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Jun 21  2017 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Jun 21  2017 41_custom
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   483 Jun 21  2017 README




=================== /etc/default/grub :

# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"



/boot/efi detected in the fstab of nvme0n1p6: UUID=BCEF-F16E     (nvme0n1p1)
Presence of EFI/Microsoft file detected: /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Presence of EFI/Boot file detected: /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
Presence of EFI/Boot file detected: /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
Presence of bkp file detected: /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi

=================== efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000,0002
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,a23a62ee-e83a-48df-8e1f-b836ac28b784,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...1................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,a23a62ee-e83a-48df-8e1f-b836ac28b784,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0002* UEFI: SanDisk Cruzer Blade 1.27, Partition 1  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(1,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x4294967245,0x800,0x3a39c40)..BO

=================== UEFI/Legacy mode:
BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
SecureBoot disabled. (maybe sec-boot, Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com)


=================== PARTITIONS & DISKS:
nvme0n1p6   : nvme0n1,  not-sepboot,    grubenv-ok  grub2,  signed grub-efi ,   update-grub,    64, with-boot,  is-os,  not--efi--part, fstab-without-boot, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, apt-get,    grub-install,   with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    notbiosboot, .
nvme0n1p1   : nvme0n1,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    is-os,  is-correct-EFI, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   not-far,    notbiosboot, /boot/efi.
nvme0n1p3   : nvme0n1,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    is-os,  not--efi--part, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    notwinboot, nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    notbiosboot, /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3.
nvme0n1p4   : nvme0n1,  not-sepboot,    no-grubenv  nogrub, no-docgrub, no-update-grub, 32, no-boot,    no-os,  not--efi--part, part-has-no-fstab,  part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot, nopakmgr,   nogrubinstall,  no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    standard,   farbios,    notbiosboot, /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4.

nvme0n1 : GPT,  no-BIOS_boot,   has-correctEFI,     not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes


=================== parted -lm:

BYT;
/dev/nvme0n1:512GB:unknown:512:512:gpt:Unknown:;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:106MB:123MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:123MB:349GB:349GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
5:349GB:353GB:4096MB:linux-swap(v1)::;
6:353GB:510GB:157GB:ext4::;
4:510GB:512GB:1887MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;

=================== lsblk:
KNAME     TYPE FSTYPE   SIZE LABEL
nvme0n1   disk          477G
nvme0n1p5 part swap     3,8G
nvme0n1p3 part ntfs   325,1G
nvme0n1p1 part vfat     100M SYSTEM
nvme0n1p6 part ext4   146,2G
nvme0n1p4 part ntfs     1,8G Windows RE tools
nvme0n1p2 part           16M

KNAME     ROTA RO RM STATE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1      0  0  0
nvme0n1p5    0  0  0       [SWAP]
nvme0n1p3    0  0  0       /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
nvme0n1p1    0  0  0       /boot/efi
nvme0n1p6    0  0  0       /
nvme0n1p4    0  0  0       /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
nvme0n1p2    0  0  0


=================== mount:
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=8117000k,nr_inodes=2029250,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=1627852k,mode=755)
/dev/nvme0n1p6 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=31,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=1726)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
tmpfs on /run/user/108 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1627852k,mode=700,uid=108,gid=114)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1627852k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
/dev/nvme0n1p3 on /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3 type fuseblk (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
/dev/nvme0n1p4 on /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4 type fuseblk (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)


=================== ls:
/sys/block/nvme0n1 (filtered):  alignment_offset badblocks bdi capability dev device discard_alignment eui ext_range holders inflight integrity mq nsid nvme0n1p1 nvme0n1p2 nvme0n1p3 nvme0n1p4 nvme0n1p5 nvme0n1p6 power queue range removable ro size slaves stat subsystem trace uevent wwid
/dev (filtered):  acpi_thermal_rel autofs block btrfs-control bus char console core cpu cpu_dma_latency cuse disk dri drm_dp_aux0 drm_dp_aux1 drm_dp_aux2 ecryptfs fb0 fd full fuse hidraw0 hidraw1 hpet hugepages hwrng i2c-0 i2c-1 i2c-10 i2c-11 i2c-12 i2c-13 i2c-14 i2c-15 i2c-16 i2c-17 i2c-18 i2c-19 i2c-2 i2c-20 i2c-21 i2c-3 i2c-4 i2c-5 i2c-6 i2c-7 i2c-8 i2c-9 initctl input kmsg kvm lightnvm log mapper mcelog media0 mei0 mem memory_bandwidth mqueue net network_latency network_throughput null nvme0 nvme0n1 nvme0n1p1 nvme0n1p2 nvme0n1p3 nvme0n1p4 nvme0n1p5 nvme0n1p6 port ppp psaux ptmx pts random rfkill rtc rtc0 shm snapshot snd stderr stdin stdout tpm0 uhid uinput urandom usb userio v4l vfio vga_arbiter vhci vhost-net video0 zero
ls /dev/mapper:  control

=================== hexdump -n512 -C /dev/nvme0n1p1
00000000  eb 58 90 4d 53 44 4f 53  35 2e 30 00 02 02 fe 19  |.X.MSDOS5.0.....|
00000010  02 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00  3f 00 ff 00 00 08 00 00  |........?.......|
00000020  00 20 03 00 01 03 00 00  00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  |. ..............|
00000030  01 00 06 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  80 01 29 6e f1 ef bc 4e  4f 20 4e 41 4d 45 20 20  |..)n...NO NAME  |
00000050  20 20 46 41 54 33 32 20  20 20 33 c9 8e d1 bc f4  |  FAT32   3.....|
00000060  7b 8e c1 8e d9 bd 00 7c  88 56 40 88 4e 02 8a 56  |{......|.V@.N..V|
00000070  40 b4 41 bb aa 55 cd 13  72 10 81 fb 55 aa 75 0a  |@.A..U..r...U.u.|
00000080  f6 c1 01 74 05 fe 46 02  eb 2d 8a 56 40 b4 08 cd  |...t..F..-.V@...|
00000090  13 73 05 b9 ff ff 8a f1  66 0f b6 c6 40 66 0f b6  |.s......f...@f..|
000000a0  d1 80 e2 3f f7 e2 86 cd  c0 ed 06 41 66 0f b7 c9  |...?.......Af...|
000000b0  66 f7 e1 66 89 46 f8 83  7e 16 00 75 39 83 7e 2a  |f..f.F..~..u9.~*|
000000c0  00 77 33 66 8b 46 1c 66  83 c0 0c bb 00 80 b9 01  |.w3f.F.f........|
000000d0  00 e8 2c 00 e9 a8 03 a1  f8 7d 80 c4 7c 8b f0 ac  |..,......}..|...|
000000e0  84 c0 74 17 3c ff 74 09  b4 0e bb 07 00 cd 10 eb  |..t.<.t.........|
000000f0  ee a1 fa 7d eb e4 a1 7d  80 eb df 98 cd 16 cd 19  |...}...}........|
00000100  66 60 80 7e 02 00 0f 84  20 00 66 6a 00 66 50 06  |f`.~.... .fj.fP.|
00000110  53 66 68 10 00 01 00 b4  42 8a 56 40 8b f4 cd 13  |Sfh.....B.V@....|
00000120  66 58 66 58 66 58 66 58  eb 33 66 3b 46 f8 72 03  |fXfXfXfX.3f;F.r.|
00000130  f9 eb 2a 66 33 d2 66 0f  b7 4e 18 66 f7 f1 fe c2  |..*f3.f..N.f....|
00000140  8a ca 66 8b d0 66 c1 ea  10 f7 76 1a 86 d6 8a 56  |..f..f....v....V|
00000150  40 8a e8 c0 e4 06 0a cc  b8 01 02 cd 13 66 61 0f  |@............fa.|
00000160  82 74 ff 81 c3 00 02 66  40 49 75 94 c3 42 4f 4f  |.t.....f@Iu..BOO|
00000170  54 4d 47 52 20 20 20 20  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |TMGR    ........|
00000180  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001a0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 0d 0a 44 69  |..............Di|
000001b0  73 6b 20 65 72 72 6f 72  ff 0d 0a 50 72 65 73 73  |sk error...Press|
000001c0  20 61 6e 79 20 6b 65 79  20 74 6f 20 72 65 73 74  | any key to rest|
000001d0  61 72 74 0d 0a 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |art.............|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ac 01 b9 01 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200

=================== hexdump -n512 -C /dev/nvme0n1p3
00000000  eb 52 90 4e 54 46 53 20  20 20 20 00 02 08 00 00  |.R.NTFS    .....|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00  3f 00 ff 00 00 a8 03 00  |........?.......|
00000020  00 00 00 00 80 00 80 00  ff 1f a2 28 00 00 00 00  |...........(....|
00000030  00 00 0c 00 00 00 00 00  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  f6 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  d4 c6 0c 6e 02 0d 6e ac  |...........n..n.|
00000050  00 00 00 00 fa 33 c0 8e  d0 bc 00 7c fb 68 c0 07  |.....3.....|.h..|
00000060  1f 1e 68 66 00 cb 88 16  0e 00 66 81 3e 03 00 4e  |..hf......f.>..N|
00000070  54 46 53 75 15 b4 41 bb  aa 55 cd 13 72 0c 81 fb  |TFSu..A..U..r...|
00000080  55 aa 75 06 f7 c1 01 00  75 03 e9 dd 00 1e 83 ec  |U.u.....u.......|
00000090  18 68 1a 00 b4 48 8a 16  0e 00 8b f4 16 1f cd 13  |.h...H..........|
000000a0  9f 83 c4 18 9e 58 1f 72  e1 3b 06 0b 00 75 db a3  |.....X.r.;...u..|
000000b0  0f 00 c1 2e 0f 00 04 1e  5a 33 db b9 00 20 2b c8  |........Z3... +.|
000000c0  66 ff 06 11 00 03 16 0f  00 8e c2 ff 06 16 00 e8  |f...............|
000000d0  4b 00 2b c8 77 ef b8 00  bb cd 1a 66 23 c0 75 2d  |K.+.w......f#.u-|
000000e0  66 81 fb 54 43 50 41 75  24 81 f9 02 01 72 1e 16  |f..TCPAu$....r..|
000000f0  68 07 bb 16 68 52 11 16  68 09 00 66 53 66 53 66  |h...hR..h..fSfSf|
00000100  55 16 16 16 68 b8 01 66  61 0e 07 cd 1a 33 c0 bf  |U...h..fa....3..|
00000110  0a 13 b9 f6 0c fc f3 aa  e9 fe 01 90 90 66 60 1e  |.............f`.|
00000120  06 66 a1 11 00 66 03 06  1c 00 1e 66 68 00 00 00  |.f...f.....fh...|
00000130  00 66 50 06 53 68 01 00  68 10 00 b4 42 8a 16 0e  |.fP.Sh..h...B...|
00000140  00 16 1f 8b f4 cd 13 66  59 5b 5a 66 59 66 59 1f  |.......fY[ZfYfY.|
00000150  0f 82 16 00 66 ff 06 11  00 03 16 0f 00 8e c2 ff  |....f...........|
00000160  0e 16 00 75 bc 07 1f 66  61 c3 a1 f6 01 e8 09 00  |...u...fa.......|
00000170  a1 fa 01 e8 03 00 f4 eb  fd 8b f0 ac 3c 00 74 09  |............<.t.|
00000180  b4 0e bb 07 00 cd 10 eb  f2 c3 0d 0a 41 20 64 69  |............A di|
00000190  73 6b 20 72 65 61 64 20  65 72 72 6f 72 20 6f 63  |sk read error oc|
000001a0  63 75 72 72 65 64 00 0d  0a 42 4f 4f 54 4d 47 52  |curred...BOOTMGR|
000001b0  20 69 73 20 63 6f 6d 70  72 65 73 73 65 64 00 0d  | is compressed..|
000001c0  0a 50 72 65 73 73 20 43  74 72 6c 2b 41 6c 74 2b  |.Press Ctrl+Alt+|
000001d0  44 65 6c 20 74 6f 20 72  65 73 74 61 72 74 0d 0a  |Del to restart..|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 8a 01  a7 01 bf 01 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200

=================== hexdump -n512 -C /dev/nvme0n1p4
00000000  eb 52 90 4e 54 46 53 20  20 20 20 00 02 08 00 00  |.R.NTFS    .....|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00  3f 00 ff 00 00 d0 65 3b  |........?.....e;|
00000020  00 00 00 00 80 00 80 00  ff 3f 38 00 00 00 00 00  |.........?8.....|
00000030  00 58 02 00 00 00 00 00  02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.X..............|
00000040  f6 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  cb 46 f5 1e 61 f5 1e ca  |.........F..a...|
00000050  00 00 00 00 fa 33 c0 8e  d0 bc 00 7c fb 68 c0 07  |.....3.....|.h..|
00000060  1f 1e 68 66 00 cb 88 16  0e 00 66 81 3e 03 00 4e  |..hf......f.>..N|
00000070  54 46 53 75 15 b4 41 bb  aa 55 cd 13 72 0c 81 fb  |TFSu..A..U..r...|
00000080  55 aa 75 06 f7 c1 01 00  75 03 e9 dd 00 1e 83 ec  |U.u.....u.......|
00000090  18 68 1a 00 b4 48 8a 16  0e 00 8b f4 16 1f cd 13  |.h...H..........|
000000a0  9f 83 c4 18 9e 58 1f 72  e1 3b 06 0b 00 75 db a3  |.....X.r.;...u..|
000000b0  0f 00 c1 2e 0f 00 04 1e  5a 33 db b9 00 20 2b c8  |........Z3... +.|
000000c0  66 ff 06 11 00 03 16 0f  00 8e c2 ff 06 16 00 e8  |f...............|
000000d0  4b 00 2b c8 77 ef b8 00  bb cd 1a 66 23 c0 75 2d  |K.+.w......f#.u-|
000000e0  66 81 fb 54 43 50 41 75  24 81 f9 02 01 72 1e 16  |f..TCPAu$....r..|
000000f0  68 07 bb 16 68 52 11 16  68 09 00 66 53 66 53 66  |h...hR..h..fSfSf|
00000100  55 16 16 16 68 b8 01 66  61 0e 07 cd 1a 33 c0 bf  |U...h..fa....3..|
00000110  0a 13 b9 f6 0c fc f3 aa  e9 fe 01 90 90 66 60 1e  |.............f`.|
00000120  06 66 a1 11 00 66 03 06  1c 00 1e 66 68 00 00 00  |.f...f.....fh...|
00000130  00 66 50 06 53 68 01 00  68 10 00 b4 42 8a 16 0e  |.fP.Sh..h...B...|
00000140  00 16 1f 8b f4 cd 13 66  59 5b 5a 66 59 66 59 1f  |.......fY[ZfYfY.|
00000150  0f 82 16 00 66 ff 06 11  00 03 16 0f 00 8e c2 ff  |....f...........|
00000160  0e 16 00 75 bc 07 1f 66  61 c3 a1 f6 01 e8 09 00  |...u...fa.......|
00000170  a1 fa 01 e8 03 00 f4 eb  fd 8b f0 ac 3c 00 74 09  |............<.t.|
00000180  b4 0e bb 07 00 cd 10 eb  f2 c3 0d 0a 41 20 64 69  |............A di|
00000190  73 6b 20 72 65 61 64 20  65 72 72 6f 72 20 6f 63  |sk read error oc|
000001a0  63 75 72 72 65 64 00 0d  0a 42 4f 4f 54 4d 47 52  |curred...BOOTMGR|
000001b0  20 69 73 20 63 6f 6d 70  72 65 73 73 65 64 00 0d  | is compressed..|
000001c0  0a 50 72 65 73 73 20 43  74 72 6c 2b 41 6c 74 2b  |.Press Ctrl+Alt+|
000001d0  44 65 6c 20 74 6f 20 72  65 73 74 61 72 74 0d 0a  |Del to restart..|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 8a 01  a7 01 bf 01 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200

=================== df -Th:

Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G  9.7M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p6 ext4      144G  3.9G  133G   3% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.8G  216K  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p1 vfat       96M   32M   65M  33% /boot/efi
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G  4.0K  1.6G   1% /run/user/108
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G   68K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/nvme0n1p3 fuseblk   326G  131G  195G  41% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4 fuseblk   1.8G  405M  1.4G  23% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4

=================== fdisk -l:
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A5A609E3-DB31-4B1A-BA2F-4788781BA932

Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048     206847    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    206848     239615     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    239616  681953279 681713664 325.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 996528128 1000214527   3686400   1.8G Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p5 681953280  689952767   7999488   3.8G Linux swap
/dev/nvme0n1p6 689952768  996528127 306575360 146.2G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.




=================== Suggested repair
The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of nvme0n1p6, using the following options:        nvme0n1p1/boot/efi,
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s   fix-windows-boot use-standard-efi-file  restore-efi-backups


=================== Final advice in case of suggested repair
Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on nvme0n1p1/efi/.../grub*.efi file!

If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your BIOS.
If your BIOS does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\...\grub*.efi


=================== User settings
The settings chosen by the user will not act on the boot.
```

Edit: The problem remains. I add a capture of my Grub:

[GRUB menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YozMC.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: Please post link to Boot-Repair's summary report. Your copy & paste lost all formatting and cannot be easily read. Also UEFI remembers entries, so you have to manually remove them, if not valid any more.

Comment: Please format terminal output by selecting the output in the editor and pressing the `{}` button.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting.

Comment: About the problem, I followed the guide that MIchaelBay posted, but it's still not working...I have disabled Secure Boot. I also followed carefully a guide to make the dual boot (https://github.com/rcasero/doc/wiki/Ubuntu-linux-on-Dell-XPS-15-(9560))...however the problem remains. This is how my Grub menu looks like now: https://imgur.com/jcKd7k6 How can I make to see just Ubuntu and Windows? The other things were created when I tried to repair it with Boot Repair on Ubuntu...